# How to compile opencv with visual studio without CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I want to compile opencv with visual studio, so the code of opencv will be on my computer like all other local code.  i.e. i want to be able to change it and debug it.
I can't find anywhere a simple directory file with all the opencv files.  It is segmented into include files, modules and similar.
All explanations in the opencv documentations use CMake.
I don't understand what exactly is CMake and why would I need it in order to compile the library locally just like all other regular code.
Can anybody explain me how to do this?

Comment: I thought the way CMake works is it will generate (amongst other options) a Visual Studio project file that you can then use to compile the code while hacking on it in VS as usual. Which means you should probably go look at a CMake tutorial.

Comment: Why can't I make the project myself, as I do from regular code?  Why do I need CMake?

Comment: CMake is what will ultimately let you make the project yourself – if OpenCV uses it correctly, just after installing it and running one command. The OpenCV developers use it so *anyone*, not just people with Visual Studio ThisYear, can make the project themselves, and contribute to the project. (Without them having to maintain project files for every development platform manually.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmake is an platform independent makefile. You can generate from cmake also visual studio projects, which can than imported into visual studio. But you need to install cmake on your computer.
To make a visual studio project call cmake like this:

```
 cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008"
```

[Cmake Wiki](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake)

Comment: There are a lot of source files, each in a different folder.  Where is "the" source code itself which I need to put in CMake?

Comment: call int the root of all folders cmake -G <yourGenerator>. It works automatically.